# Recursive Function through dict of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, recursive-query

Given this data structure

```
[{'name': 'Business Operations', 
  'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations'], 
  'team_view': ['Snaptest'], 
  'test_sub_subfolder': [
       {'name': 'test_sub', 
        'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
        'team_view': ['hugo']}], 
  'test_sub2_subfolder': [
       {'name': 'test_sub2', 
        'test_sub_subfolder': [
            {'name': 'test_sub_sub', 
             'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
             'team_view': ['hugo']}]}]}]
```

I'm trying to write a recursive function that will give me access to all the elements, essentially printing them out. The nested structure can be of arbitrary length, but will always follow this format.

My first attempt at this is

```
def recurse_over_object(dict_obj):
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        if 'subfolder' in key:
            for pair in recurse_over_object(value[0]):
                print(key, *pair)
                # yield (key, *pair)
        else:
            print(key, value)
            # yield (key, value)
```

The issue here is that as I go down the tree I call for the value `subfolder` and go down that route, but in this example I have two subfolders at the same level (`test_sub` and `test_sub2`) and I need to get values for both of them.

Does anyone know of any fancy ways to do this ?
I can definitely restructure the data input if required to make it easier, for example one idea I had was to make the subfolders on the same level a `list` but then I was struggling in one recursive function to iterate through those elements.

Any help of ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: where's the recursive in your attempt? You should call recurse_over_object within recurse_over_object AND have an exit point.

Comment: good call, i changed the function name last min

Comment: basically if subfolder is in the key then recall the function 'recurse_over_object'

Comment: Convert this to XML and use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to fetch that you need.

Comment: I think you're almost there. (1) you must have an exit point in every recursive function. (2) use DFS algorithm it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iteratively call `recurse_over_object` under `if 'subfolder' in key:`. So like:

```
def recurse_over_object(dict_obj):
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        if 'subfolder' in key:
            for item in value:
                recurse_over_object(item)
        else:
            print(key, value)
```

Then

```
for d in data:
    recurse_over_object(d)
```

outputs:

```
name Business Operations
team_edit ['BusinessOperations']
team_view ['Snaptest']
name test_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
name test_sub2
name test_sub_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested structure that contains lists, dicts, and strings. The recursing function can test that to decide what to do with the elements:

```py
def get_branches(x, acc=()):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k,v in x.items():
            yield from get_branches(v, acc+(k,))
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        for k in x:
            yield from get_branches(k, acc)
    else:
        yield acc + (x,)

x = [{'name': 'Business Operations', 
  'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations'], 
  'team_view': ['Snaptest'], 
  'test_sub_subfolder': [
       {'name': 'test_sub', 
        'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
        'team_view': ['hugo']}], 
  'test_sub2_subfolder': [
       {'name': 'test_sub2', 
        'test_sub_subfolder': [
            {'name': 'test_sub_sub', 
             'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
             'team_view': ['hugo']}]}]}]

print(list( get_branches(x) ))
```

Output:

```py
[('name', 'Business Operations'),
 ('team_edit', 'BusinessOperations'),
 ('team_view', 'Snaptest'),
 ('test_sub_subfolder', 'name', 'test_sub'),
 ('test_sub_subfolder', 'team_edit', 'BusinessOperations'),
 ('test_sub_subfolder', 'team_edit', 'Freddy'),
 ('test_sub_subfolder', 'team_view', 'hugo'),
 ('test_sub2_subfolder', 'name', 'test_sub2'),
 ('test_sub2_subfolder', 'test_sub_subfolder', 'name', 'test_sub_sub'),
 ('test_sub2_subfolder', 'test_sub_subfolder', 'team_edit', 'BusinessOperations'),
 ('test_sub2_subfolder', 'test_sub_subfolder', 'team_edit', 'Freddy'),
 ('test_sub2_subfolder', 'test_sub_subfolder', 'team_view', 'hugo')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow your lead on using `yield()` (as well as `print`), here is adjusted code that I think will do what your question is asking. Note that the final `x = list( ... )` statement is intended to invoke the generator your function creates.

```py
dataStructure = [
    {'name': 'Business Operations', 
     'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations'],
     'team_view': ['Snaptest'], 
     'test_sub_subfolder': [
         {'name': 'test_sub', 
          'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
          'team_view': ['hugo']}], 
     'test_sub2_subfolder': [
         {'name': 'test_sub2',
          'test_sub_subfolder': [
              {'name': 'test_sub_sub', 
               'team_edit': ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy'], 
               'team_view': ['hugo']}]}]}
]
def recurse_over_object(dict_obj):
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        if 'subfolder' in key:
            '''
            for pair in recurse_over_object(value[0]):
                print(key, *pair)
                yield (key, *pair)
            '''
            print(key, *list(recurse_over_object(value[0])))
            yield(key, *list(recurse_over_object(value[0])))
        else:
            print(key, value)
            yield (key, value)   

x = list(recurse_over_object(dataStructure[0]))
```

Output:

```
name Business Operations
team_edit ['BusinessOperations']
team_view ['Snaptest']
name test_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
test_sub_subfolder ('name', 'test_sub') ('team_edit', ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']) ('team_view', ['hugo'])
name test_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
name test_sub2
name test_sub_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
test_sub_subfolder ('name', 'test_sub_sub') ('team_edit', ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']) ('team_view', ['hugo'])
name test_sub_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
test_sub2_subfolder ('name', 'test_sub2') ('test_sub_subfolder', ('name', 'test_sub_sub'), ('team_edit', ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']), ('team_view', ['hugo']))
name test_sub2
name test_sub_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
test_sub_subfolder ('name', 'test_sub_sub') ('team_edit', ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']) ('team_view', ['hugo'])
name test_sub_sub
team_edit ['BusinessOperations', 'Freddy']
team_view ['hugo']
```