# How to create a flat data structure from a tree?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a tree structure such as (A JSON object):

```
     1
   /   \
   2    3
  /\
 4  5
```

I need to convert this into the following:

```
   1 1 1
   | | |
   2 2 3
   | |
   4 5
```

After some days of trying to do this in Python, I'm struggling. This is a question that came up in an intermediate DSA course.

I'm looking for an 'approach' rather than a solution that I can explore.
Are there any known methods for this?

Using a small dummy data (INPUT):

```
{
    "id": "csiudfysd",
    "events": [
       {"value": "refuelling", "dates": ["23rd","24th"]}, 
       {"value": "deicing"}
    ]
}
```

If i convert this to a tree it would be:

```
          "csiudfysd"   
           /        \
   "refuelling"    "deicing"
         /\
     23rd  24th
```

I've tried building a list of nodes and assigning the parent_id to each:

```
[

{'parent_id': '1',
  'value': 'deicing'},

 {'parent_id': '1',
  'value': 'refuelling'},

  {'parent_id': '2',
  'value': '23rd'},

  {'parent_id': '2',
  'value': '24th'},
]
```

From this list, I can then look up the parents in a "lookup" map.

```
{

'1': {'id': 'csiudfysd'}
'2': {value: "refuelling"}
'3': {value: "deicing"}
}
```

with the desired output to be (OUTPUT):

```
[
    {
        "id": "csiudfysd",
        "value": "refuelling"
        "date": 23rd
    },
    {
        "id": "csiudfysd",
        "value": "refuelling"
        "date": 24th
    },
    {
        "id": "csiudfysd",
        "value": "deicing"
    }
]
```

But this seems like a hacky approach I came up with, I imagine there's a better way, but I can't see what that would be from the course material or online reading - I'm hiting a dead end

Comment: What is the input you get? It seems you are focused on building a tree data structure, which is a question on itself (without regard of the output that is expected here). Which are you asking about?

Comment: @trincot ah yes, I just updated the question with an example input and output. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense? I'm asking about whether there is a better way to tackle this:

e.g. Build a tree and then traverse through it to build the output. Rather than built the tree + a lookup map + a list of the children. Then eventually use these to create the output

Comment: I'm not sure which of the code blocks represents the input? Can you clarify? If it is the one with "events", how does this represent a tree? Can you give a complete example, and then complete code you have to process that input and produce a tree, and where your code has an issue?

Comment: Yes, that's the input. I think my question is more how should I approach this, should I even build a tree in the first place?

Comment: Can you show what the input would be like if the tree has more than 2 levels? It would be useful to have a bit more extensive example, as I don't see how this object would look with a larger tree.

Comment: I wrote a function `get_branches` which lists all branches of a json tree, in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71430868/3080723). It looks like it would answer the question in your title, as well as the explanation with the (1, (2, (7,)), (5, (9, 8))) example. But it's unclear how to adapt it to fit your json example.

Comment: I updated the question for clarity & thank you @Stef i'll take a look at that now :D

Comment: The main issue I have with your json example is that the function would need to "guess" that `"id"` and `"value"` are both "parent name", whereas `"events"` and `"dates"` both mean "children".

Comment: Should we assume that the dicts in your input data will always have exactly one key whose value is a non-list, and potentially one other key which is a list?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function that iterates through a tree using depth-first-search, and outputs a list of branches, is relatively straightforward.

The main issue I have with your examples is that the function should be able to "guess" which field designates the parent name, and which field designates the list of children. In your example, both `"id"` and `"value"` are considered the parent name, and both `"events"` and `"dates"` are considered the list of children.

In the following code I assumed that every dict should have either:

- 1 element, if the node doesn't have children;
- 2 elements, exactly one of which is a list, if the node has a list of children.

```py
def get_branches(d, acc=None, nodename=''):
    if acc is None:
        acc = {}
    if not isinstance(d, dict):      # leaf
        yield acc | {nodename: d}
    elif len(d) == 1:                # node without child
        (fieldname, x), = d.items()
        yield acc | {fieldname: x}
    elif len(d) == 2:                # node with children
        (fieldname_a, a), (fieldname_b, b) = d.items()
        if isinstance(b, list) and not isinstance(a, list):
            # a is name, b is children
            for child in b:
                yield from get_branches(child, acc | {fieldname_a: a}, fieldname_b.removesuffix('s'))
        elif isinstance(a, list) and not isinstance(b, list):
            # b is name, a is children
            for child in a:
                yield from get_branches(child, acc | {fieldname_b: b}, fieldname_a.removesuffix('s'))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Could not identify which is nodename and which is children list')
    else:
        raise ValueError('dict has more than 2 elements')

j = {'id': 'csiudfysd', 'events': [{'value': 'refuelling', 'dates': ['23rd', '24th']}, {'value': 'deicing'}]}

print(list(get_branches(j)))
# [{'id': 'csiudfysd', 'value': 'refuelling', 'date': '23rd'},
#  {'id': 'csiudfysd', 'value': 'refuelling', 'date': '24th'},
#  {'id': 'csiudfysd', 'value': 'deicing'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that builds resulting dicts in a *postorder* traversal (runs on Python 3.8):

```
def getpaths(root, key=""):
    if not isinstance(root, dict):  # It's a leaf value for which we received the key
        yield { key[:-1] if key.endswith("s") else key : root }
    elif len(root) < 2:  # It's a leaf that includes the key. Return as-is
        yield root
    else:  # It's an internal node
        # Get first two key/value pairs from dict
        pair = list(root.items())[:2]
        # Get the children list and the other key/value pair
        (_, children), (key, val) = pair[::-1] if isinstance(pair[1][1], list) else pair
        # Extend results from subtrees with current key/value pair 
        yield from ({**{key:val}, **res} for ch in children for res in getpaths(ch, key))
```

Example:

```
root = {
    "id": "csiudfysd",
    "events": [
       {"value": "refuelling", "dates": ["23rd","24th", {}]}, 
       {"value": "deicing"}
    ]
}

for path in getpaths(root):
    print(path)
```

This code assumes the format of the input follows these rules:

- Each dict has either 1 or 2 keys, and if 2, then one of them has a list as value
- Lists are never empty

If not, the function will still yield results, but they might not be what was expected (if anything).